# File is downloaded instead of being displayed in the browser

Tags: clojure, ring, luminus

I have created a brand new app from the luminus app template using `lein new luminus my-app +postgres +auth +cljs +swagger`. In the generated file `src/clj/my_app/routes/home.clj` the following compojure route is created:

`(GET "/docs" [] (response/ok (-> "docs/docs.md" io/resource slurp)))`

When I try to access `localhost:3000/docs` the file is simply downloaded instead of displayed in the browser. It happens both with Chrome and Safari.

It seems related to `ring.util.http-response/ok` since I can reproduce the behavior using this route too:

`(GET "/hi" [] (response/ok "hi"))`.

A file "hi" is then downloaded with file content "hi".

Any ideas on what's causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response handler doesn't set `Content-Type` for your response body.

You can do it using `ring.util.http-response/content-type`:

```
(GET "/hi" [] (-> "hi"
                  (response/ok)
                  (response/content-type "text/plain")))
```

You can also wrap your handler in [`ring.middleware.content-type/wrap-content-type`](https://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.middleware.content-type.html#var-wrap-content-type) so the headers are "guessed" based on the file extension from the URI.