# Why are my endpoints not passing headers/cookies across and responding as expected in Clojure using ring?

Tags: clojure, ring

I want to redirect from an api endpoint to a another endpoint passing headers and cookies through.

Below is the redirect from the endpoint I want to redirect from to the other endpoint with the header and cookies.

```
(GET "/the-endpoint"
     request
     (-> (response/redirect "/another-endpoint")
         (response/header "Authorization" (str "Bearer " "some-token"))
         (response/set-cookie "access_token" "some-token")))
```

Note that I have put the token into both the header and the cookies for testing purposes as neither the header nor the cookies are being passed to `/another-endpoint`

I have a simple GET for the other endpoint that returns a response with a silly body for now.

I am watching the values of the headers and cookies in the Network tab in the Chrome DevTools. I experience strange behavior in this handler whereby the body of the response is downloaded by Chrome instead of being displayed in the browser.

```
(GET "/another-endpoint"
     request
     (response/response "something random to be used as the body for now"))
```

I see the request in the network which shows a 200 status but the request header and cookies that I have passed through have not been set. I thought it was a CORS issue so I did the redirect on the same api and experienced the same behavior.

I am using:

```
[ring/ring-core "1.6.3"]
```

Essentially what I want to know is:

1. Why is the `Authorization` header and `access_token` cookie not passed to `/another-endpoint`?
2. Why is the `/another-endpoint` resource being downloaded by Chrome instead of being displayed in the browser?

What I am trying to do:

1. User logs into a website and clicks on a button to do something.
2. That button navigates to the api endpoint that will generate a jwt.
3. The api needs to redirect to an external api with the jwt in the header to be silently authenticated.
4. Once authenticated, the user needs to seamlessly be navigated to the dashboard of the external website so that they can proceed (no manual log in).

Right now I am testing everything on the same api.

Comment: (2) I need a content-type. The detault I notice is set to `application/edn; charset=utf-8` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35548372/file-is-downloaded-instead-of-being-displayed-in-the-browser

Comment: Chrome doesn't know how to display edn and will consider this a file and save it.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. :)

Comment: Basically, the problem is that you can't set headers in a redirect, besides the Location header itself. This is a HTTP restriction, that actually makes sense if you think about what's happening: telling the client to make a new request. The client retains control over which headers it is going to send.

Comment: So if I want to pass the cookies, session and headers through to a new page, do I need to redirect from the client instead (not server side using ring)? When I do a server side redirect to a page on the same domain then none of those are passed through to the redirected page (unless I inspected it incorrectly).

Comment: When the client follows the redirect, it will use whatever cookies and/or authentication credentials it already has for wherever it is redirected to. So if you redirect to the same domain (or subdomain), then the redirected page should get the same cookies and credentials. It's just that in the redirect response, you don't have any control over how the second request is made. (Technically, the client can decide not to even follow redirects.)